# Creating hyperlink on the highcharts stacked bar chat

Tags: highcharts, stackedbarseries

```js
var s1 = "{ name : \'Space1\', data :[5, 3, 4, 7] },";
var s2 = "{ name :\'Space2\', data:[5, 4, 7] },";
var s3 = "{ name : \'Space3\', data:[5, 3, 7] }";
var series = s1+s2+s3;

var chartdata = {
   chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Cost/Env'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Prod', 'Test', 'Dev', 'Sandbox']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Cost of apps'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -30,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{}]
   
};

chartdata.series.data = series;
$('#stackedBar1').highcharts(chartdata);
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="stackedBar1" style="display: inline; float: left; height: 300px; margin: 0px;"></div>
```

I have created a dashboard using Ko, highcharts and the data using JSON. I have to create a stacked bar chat, in which the series data is changing dynamically for each category. Example cat1 may have 3 series objects, and cat2 may have 0, cat3 may have 10 etc....I have two questions,
1. how to include this dynamic JSON objects into the series object. (I referred links, i got the solution, i have to try them)
2. Once i click on a bar-chat at a specific position(color), i have to show detailed information, (i already designed and currently showing in my dashboard, i need to switch to that part). Is their any information available to handle such situation.

thanks in advance,
shankar

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use a ajax to load json (for example $.getJSON) and load data. Please not that data needs to be in correct format.

Further information about working with data you can find [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing)

2) You can use tooltip [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) to customise content and print that on hover.

Referring to click event, you can add this action by [point.events.click](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click) and then show your custom popup / div etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response.....I currently worked on point one....I have added my code, i have created Variable to represent my Sample JSON and tried to insert them into Series data. but it is not working.